# Blazor Maui App is Not Displaying Images that are in a Razor Class Library project

Tags: razor, blazor, assets, maui, razor-class-library

The **images are referenced in a razor component** that's defined in a Razor Class Library in the "wwwroot/Images" folder.

I've included a project reference to this Razor Class Library in my Blazor Maui Client App.

The problem I'm having is that the image is not showing up.

Initially I had it as:

`<img src="../wwwroot/Images/CISA_Logo_183px.png" />`

then I tried:

`<img src="_content/CSETRazorClassLibrary/wwwroot/images/CISA_Logo_183px.png" />`

and I'm not having any luck getting the image to display.

Is there something else I need to configure in the Blazor Maui app to make this work?

I'm using Visual Studio 2022 Preview Version 17.3.0 Preview 3.0 and I'm on a Windows 11 Pro Version 21H2

Comment: `_content/CSETRazorClassLibrary/images/CISA_Logo_183px.png` `_content/CSETRazorClassLibrary/` is the `wwwroot` folder of the RCL. or `src="Images/CISA_Logo_183px.png"` if it is not content and copied to the folder.

Comment: @BrianParker Thank you for replying so quickly.  I tried that as well and it did not work.

Comment: I just spun up a test app then added a RCL. `src="_content/RazorClassLibrary1/background.png"` worked. Did you add a project reference to your RCL? `background.png` is in the `wwwroot` folder of the rcl.

Comment: Also when I file explore to the "obj/Debug/net6.0-android/assets/wwwroot" folder in the MauiBlazor client app project, I see the "index.html" and css folder and files but nothing about images.

Comment: @BrianParker:  What version of Visual Studio of the preview version of 2022 are you currently on?

Comment: I downloaded the latest version about 20minutes before i saw your question. 17.3.0 Preview 3.0

Comment: I ran the App in both windows and on a Android emulator and the picture was present.

Answer (score 2):

The src is wrong. `_content/CSETRazorClassLibrary/` is the wwwroot folder of the RCL. So the path should be `_content/CSETRazorClassLibrary/images/CISA_Logo_183px.png` . Here is a test I ran up to illustrate the path resolution.

[image]

```
<img src="_content/RazorClassLibrary1/background.png" />
```

[image]

```
@page "/"
@using RazorClassLibrary1

<h1>Hello, world!</h1>


<Component1 />
```

[image]

Comment: I have the image referenced inside a component defined in the razor class library.  Could you try adding the image inside your "Component1.razor" file and then add the <component1 /> in your index.razor file in your maui project?

Comment: @Darlene I added a screen shot for you.

Answer (score 0):

Turns out after I updated Visual Studio I was able to get it to work.  So it appears that the version I had was the reason I could not see the image.

Comment: To help make sure this answer is useful to future visitors, can you specify what the version of Visual Studio was that you started with, and what the version you upgraded to was?